# Access denied when trying to access http://localhost/phpmyadmin. Receiving the error: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, sockets, phpmyadmin

I am unable to access phpmyadmin on the localhost. On the phpmyadmin page it says "MySQL said: 2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)."

I am also unable to login to my mysql as well since I am unable to find the password to login. When I enter `-u root -p`into the terminal I am prompted to enter a password and after I hit enter I receive the error message `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. I already have XAMPP installed and I also made sure the mysql was installed locally by entering `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. I am at lost as to why I am having this issue and how to solve it.

Comment: So, is MySQL running? How and when did you achieve that? Which instructions/manual are you following?

Comment: I already tried those answers from that post and it still did not remedy my situation.

Comment: MySQL is not running on XAMPP but it seems that I can start it using "sudo service mysql start".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue. It turns out I already had MAMP installed (in addition to XAMPP) and it was already running MySQL on the localhost, but not the Apache server. I simply stopped all servers on XAMPP and was able to start Apache and MySQL on MAMP and then was able to access phpmyadmin on the localhost.